# Saving Video File Name with FilePond in Laravel Without Null 'name' Field

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-8, filepond

I'm facing an issue with FilePond in my Laravel project. When I use FilePond to upload a video, the 'name' field in the 'videos' table is saved as null. I suspect it's due to FilePond modifying the input field. I've tried various solutions, including changing selectors, but nothing seems to work. How can I ensure that the 'name' field in the 'videos' table is populated with the uploaded video's name when using FilePond?

I'm working on a Laravel project initiated by another developer, and I've encountered an issue with FilePond. In my HTML, I have the following code:

```
    <div class="field is-normal">
      <div class="field-label is-normal">
          <label class="label required">فيديو</label>
      </div><br>
                  <input type="file" name="video"  class="filepond">
                  
    </div>
```

I noticed that when I inspect the element, the code transforms into something else, but when I view the page source (Ctrl+U), it's the same. Here's the JavaScript code in `app.blade.php`

```
const inputElementvideo = document.querySelector('[name="video"].filepond');
const csrfToken = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');

FilePond.registerPlugin(FilePondPluginFileValidateType);

FilePond.create(inputElementvideo).setOptions({
    acceptedFileTypes: ['video/*'],
    server: {
        process: '{{ route('videoupload') }}',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken,
        }
    },
});
```

I suspect FilePond might be altering the input field. How can I ensure that the 'name' field in the 'videos' table is populated with the uploaded video's name when using FilePond? Please note that I didn't initiate this project, and I'm trying to work within the existing setup.
How can I ensure that the 'name' field in the 'videos' table is populated with the uploaded video's name when using FilePond? Please note that I didn't start this project and I'm trying to work within the existing setup.

here is the store method that I use:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        
        
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|min:3',
            'first_name' => 'required|min:3',
            'last_name' => 'required|min:3',
            'pseudo' => 'nullable|min:3',
            'birthday' => 'nullable|date',
            'birthday_place' => 'nullable',
            'death' => 'nullable|date',
            'family_status' => 'nullable|min:3',
            'date_joining' => 'nullable|date',
            'zone' => 'nullable',
            'side' => 'nullable|min:3',
            'division' => 'nullable|min:3',
            'responsibility' => 'nullable|min:3',
            'resume' => 'nullable|min:3',
            'keys' => 'nullable|min:3',
            'hash' => 'nullable',
            'type' => 'nullable',
            'indexinfg_aid' => 'nullable',
            'notice' => 'nullable',

            'pays' =>'nullable',
            'emplois' =>'nullable',

            'recorde_date' =>'nullable|date',
            'recorde_place' =>'nullable',
            'time' =>'nullable',
            'animator' =>'nullable',
            'localisation' =>'nullable',
            'links' =>'nullable',

            
            
        ]);
        $request->merge(['user_id' => auth()->user()->id]);
        $temoignage =  Temoignage::create($request->all());
       // table video
        $data= new Video();
        $data->temoignage_id=$temoignage->id;
        $data->recorde_date=$request->recorde_date;
        $data->recorde_place=$request->recorde_place;
        $data->time=$request->time;
        $data->animator=$request->animator;
        $data->localisation=$request->localisation;
        $data->links=$request->links;

        if ($request->video != null) {
            $cleanedFileName = basename($request->video); // Nettoyez le nom du fichier
            $sourceFilePath = public_path('folder/tmp/video/' . $cleanedFileName);
            $destinationFilePath = public_path('folder/video/' . $cleanedFileName);
            
            if (file_exists($sourceFilePath)) {
                File::copy($sourceFilePath, $destinationFilePath);
                $data->name = $cleanedFileName;
            } else {
                // Gérer le cas où le fichier source n'existe pas
                // Peut-être une redirection ou un message d'erreur approprié
            }

            if ($request->hasFile('video')) {
                $videoFile = $request->file('video');
                $videoFileName = 'mojahidine' . time() . '.' . $videoFile->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $videoFile->move(public_path('folder/video/'), $videoFileName);
                //$video->name = $videoFileName;
                $data->name = $videoFileName;
            }
        }

        $data->save();
        // table photo
        if($photos = $request->file("photo"))
        {
            $count=1;
            foreach($photos as $imagefile){
              $string=uniqid();
              $img= new Photo;
              
              $fileName =  'mojahidine'.time().$string.'.'.$imagefile->getClientOriginalExtension();  
              $imagefile->move(public_path('folder/photo'), $fileName);
    
             $img->name = $fileName;
             $img->temoignage_id = $temoignage->id;
            
             $img->save();
             $count++;
           }
        }
        // table docs 
        if($docs = $request->file("docs"))
        {
            $count=1;
            foreach($docs as $imagefile){
              $string=uniqid();
              $img= new Doc;
              
              $fileName =  'mojahidine'.time().$string.'.'.$imagefile->getClientOriginalExtension();  
              $imagefile->move(public_path('folder/docs'), $fileName);
    
             $img->name = $fileName;
             $img->temoignage_id = $temoignage->id;
            
             $img->save();
             $count++;
           }
        }


        return redirect()->route('temoignage.index')->with('success','تم إنشاء الشهادة  بنجاح');
    }
```